# How to convert the data following into range on excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data like following:

[image]

If I want it to convert it into specific ranges like following:

[image]

How should I do it on excel?

Comment: Is the second column a frequency count of the number in the first column?

Comment: Yes, "Total Count" would be sum of the 2nd column of the top table lying in the given range

Comment: Resume your data with Pivot Tables grouping it: [Group or ungroup data in a PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725). You can group it by intervals of 50 and then sum up the count of your second column.

Comment: @joeswig did you try the approaches as mentioned in answers below.

Answer (score 2):

As [**Foxfire And Burns And Burns**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9199828/foxfire-and-burns-and-burns) has mentioned, it is best to use a `PIVOT TABLES` and then **Group** it by **intervals of 50**. Using `Pivot Tables` and then `Group & Ungroup` is pretty easy and highly suggested by all excel experts in this community.

However if you are looking to use a formula to create that range (`RAFFLE TICKET`) that's how its known, then you may try the formula mentioned below,

Formula used in cell `A2`

```
=(ROWS($A$2:A2)-1)*50&"-"&ROWS($A$2:A2)*50
```

And Fill Down!

For those using **Excel 2021 & O365**, may try this one as well

```
=SEQUENCE(11,,0,50)&"-"&SEQUENCE(11,,50,50)
```

Next to get the total counts you can use `SUMPRODUCT FUNCTION`, which creates an array of `TRUE's & FALSE's` & multiplies the same with the corresponding ranges accordingly, so the formula used in cell `B2`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$E$16>=--LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2)-1))*($E$2:$E$16<=--RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("-",A2)))*$F$2:$F$16)
```

And Fill Down!

[image: RAFFLE_TICKET_RANGE]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create the Dummy column (C column) which will contain the limits of your ranges. And then you will fill values into the D column thanks to this formula :

```
=C2 & "-" & C3
```

So the first value Total Count column can be filled with (in column E) :

```
=SUMIF(A$2:A$16;"<"& C3;B$2:B$16)-SUMIF(A$2:A$16;"<"&C2;B$2:B$16)
```

and then you can extend the formula through the other cells of the column.

This SUMIF() formula calculates values for range <50 minus values for range <0 (for Range 0-50). For Range 50-100, this formula will calculate the sum for range <100 minus sum for range <50, and so on..
[image]
The

Remark : Here the limits of the range are not considered for example if Valeur =50 the formula in Range column doen't count it. If you want to consider them in account, you can modify the values of the Dummy column to 0; 49.999999; or 50.000001 (left for you as an exercice :) ).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to create a helper column, using a formula like `=ROUNDDOWN(A1,0)`.

Once you have this (let's say in column "C"), you can sum your values using the basic `=SUMIF()` function, something like:

```
=SUMIF(C$1:C$8,3,B$1:B$8)
```

(This will sum the values of the cells from B1 to B8, in case the corresponding values in column "C" are equal to 3, which means that the values in column "A" are between 150 and 199.99....